# Snowflake returning float instead of integer

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

select 5 - 4.2 ,snowflake is returning 0.8 as it should in a standalone query.
but when 5-4.2 is happening inside script it's returning 0.7999999999999998 , what kind of magic is this

Till yesterday it was working. From today there was change in precision

When I use below SQL SELECT SUM(0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+2) O/P: 5.0
If he same values are coming from table with float column
Select SUM(column) from table
O/P: 5.000000000000001

Comment: The first version is returning a float not an integer. The fact that the two versions return slightly different values is standard behaviour for floats - if this is an issue for you then you you need to explicitly handle this by rounding, converting to other datatypes etc. This behaviour is described here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#float-float4-float8

Comment: Can you share the script? It should always return 0.8.

Comment: I have updated my question with the script

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "in a script", so probably you mean in a JavaScript script?

This is how floating point numbers usually work.

Trying this in my Chrome console:

```js
> 5 - 4.2
< 0.7999999999999998
```

Please post more of your code (in a new question maybe), if you'd like help with specifics.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for inputs. I saw this in snowflake query. And it was working these many days and started breaking from yesterday. For now I used round.

Comment: When I use below SQL
SELECT SUM(0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+2)
O/P: 5.0 
If he same values are coming from table with float column
Select SUM(column) from table
O/P: 5.000000000000001

Comment: Please post more of your code (in a new question maybe), if you'd like help with specifics.

Comment: I have updated my question with the script

Comment: I can't reproduce your results in Snowflake, but note that this is expected for floats according to the IEEE. These are different experiments in the JS console, for example: https://i.imgur.com/dUiey8l.png.